# The type or namespace name 'OwinStartupAttributeAttribute' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I am compiling some code that I did not write.

When I do Build -> Build Solution I get this error:

```
The type of namespace name 'OwinStartupAttributeAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

On this line of code:

```
using Microsoft.Owin;
using Owin;

[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(CCACustomerPayment.Startup))]
```

So, I try to do this:

```
PM> install-package microsoft.owin
```

And get this error:

```
Attempting to gather dependency information for package 'microsoft.owin.4.0.0' with respect to project 'CustomerPayment', targeting '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5'
Gathering dependency information took 1.35 sec
Attempting to resolve dependencies for package 'microsoft.owin.4.0.0' with DependencyBehavior 'Lowest'
One or more unresolved package dependency constraints detected in the existing packages.config file. All dependency constraints must be resolved to add or update packages. If these packages are being updated this message may be ignored, if not the following error(s) may be blocking the current package operation: 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.0.1 constraint: Owin (>= 1.0.0)', 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 3.0.1 constraint: Microsoft.Owin (>= 3.0.1)', 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 3.0.1 constraint: Owin (>= 1.0.0)', 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 3.0.1 constraint: Microsoft.Owin (>= 3.0.1)', 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies 2.1.0 constraint: Owin (>= 1.0.0)', 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies 2.1.0 constraint: Microsoft.Owin (>= 2.1.0)', 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 2.1.0 constraint: Owin (>= 1.0.0)', 'Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth 2.1.0 constraint: Microsoft.Owin (>= 2.1.0)'
Resolving dependency information took 0 ms
Resolving actions to install package 'microsoft.owin.4.0.0'
Resolved actions to install package 'microsoft.owin.4.0.0'
Retrieving package 'Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Retrieving package 'Owin 1.0.0' from 'nuget.org'.
Adding package 'Owin.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\Users\ME\source\Customer\customerpayment\CustomerPayment\packages'
Added package 'Owin.1.0.0' to folder 'C:\Users\Me\source\Customer\customerpayment\CustomerPayment\packages'
Added package 'Owin.1.0.0' to 'packages.config'
Successfully installed 'Owin 1.0.0' to CustomerPayment
Install failed. Rolling back...
Package 'Microsoft.Owin.4.0.0 : Owin [1.0.0, )' does not exist in project 'CustomerPayment'
Removed package 'Owin.1.0.0' from 'packages.config'
Package 'Microsoft.Owin.4.0.0 : Owin [1.0.0, )' does not exist in folder 'C:\Users\Me\source\ Customer\customerpayment\CustomerPayment\packages'
Removing package 'Owin.1.0.0' from folder 'C:\Users\ME\source\Customer\customerpayment\CustomerPayment\packages'
Removed package 'Owin.1.0.0' from folder 'C:\Users\ME\source\Customer\customerpayment\CustomerPayment\packages'
Executing nuget actions took 529.79 ms
install-package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.Owin 4.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETFramework,Version=v4.5', but the package 
does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package microsoft.owin
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

Time Elapsed: 00:00:01.9633227
```

I have also tried adding `--version 4.5` and other variations, but that does not work either.

When I look at `Project -> Add Reference` I do not see any option for Microsoft.owin.

How do I get this code to compile?

Comment: You need to target at least 4.5.1

Comment: What do I click on to "target at least 4.5.1"?  that is, on the install command or do I change something in web.config?

Comment: No, in VS use Project > Properties > Application tab, "Target framework" setting.

Comment: I updated to 4.6.1 and then was able to run the install command.  Post that as an answer and I accept it.

Comment: Feel free to use what you learned to complete your Q+A.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to solve the problem per @HansPassant suggestions:

I changed to .Net 4.6.1 using these steps:

1. Right click on the project
2. Select `Properties`
3. Set Application -> Target Framework to 4.6.1
4. Select `Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console`
5. Type `install-package microsoft.owin`
6. Expect to see a successful install

Answer (score 0):

microsoft.owin is not enought to start the project, also add Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.
With this you should be able to start it.

Comment: What do I click on to add it?  When I do Project -> Add Reference I don't see anything with Owin.

Comment: @MichaelPotter it is a nuget, just install it into the project.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i remember , you may also need to reference `Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb`.
[Download it from NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb/)